# Children going out of parent element

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/zP49Z/

As you can see, the children [update] are going out of the parent element [feeds]. How can I fix this?

```
#updates {
    background: #B8C1C2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: auto;
}
#feeds {
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
}
.update {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #929493;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow-x: hidden; if you want the feed to be contained and scroll. View here: [jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/zP49Z/2](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/zP49Z/2/)

```
#feeds {
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Then I cannot scroll through the "feeds".

Comment: You can use overflow-x: hidden; if you want the feed to be contained and scroll. View here: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/zP49Z/2/